# Will it detriment my security if I allow all connections from localhost through iptables?

Tags: linux, security, iptables, firewall, localhost

Under my current configuration, 
`iptables` will block every inbound connection, even if coming from `localhost`. In some cases, I need `localhost` to connect to itself. If I create a rule that allows all inbound connections from `localhost`, will this detriment my server's security? For example, could an attacker abuse this firewall rule in any way?

Comment: Loopback is only a risk when folks set it as routable via sysctl, as is often done in openstack.  By default, nobody can get there unless you route them there through an application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that localhost (127.0.0.1) is the loopback interface on the system. If someone can snoop traffic on that interface, they are already on your system so you have worse problems to deal with.